# Programming Collective Intellegence chapter 5 Example doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I study a Chapter 5 from O'Reilly Programming Collective Intellegence and after running a part of code:

```
import time
import random
import math

people = [('Seymour','BOS'),
          ('Franny','DAL'),
          ('Zooey','CAK'),
          ('Walt','MIA'),
          ('Buddy','ORD'),
          ('Les','OMA')]
# Laguardia
destination='LGA'

flights={}
file = open('schedule.txt','r')
for line in file:
    origin,dest,depart,arrive,price=line.strip().split(',')
    flights.setdefault((origin,dest),[])
    # Add details to the list of possible flights
    flights[(origin,dest)].append((depart,arrive,int(price)))

def getminutes(t):
    x=time.strptime(t,'%H:%M')
    return x[3]*60+x[4]
def printschedule(r):
    for d in range(len(r)//2):
        name=people[d][0]
        origin=people[d][1]
        out=flights[(origin,destination)][r[d]]
        ret=flights[(destination,origin)][r[d]]
        print('%10s%10s %5s-%5s $%3s %5s-%5s $%3s' % (name,origin,out[0],out[1],out[2],ret[0],ret[1],ret[2]))
s=[1,4,3,2,7,3,6,3,2,4,5,3]
printschedule(s)
```

with text file(schedule.txt):

```
LGA,MIA,20:27,23:42,169
MIA,LGA,19:53,22:21,173
LGA,BOS,6:39,8:09,86
BOS,LGA,6:17,8:26,89
LGA,BOS,8:23,10:28,149
```

I get an error:

```
out=flights[(origin,destination)][r[d]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't understand how to fix this error. Please, help.

Comment: O'Reilly books usually have errata available (in this case they're [here](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596529321)); you may want to check to see if this is addressed.  It looks like your schedule.txt is incomplete, since as Scott Hunter noted there are no flights from `DAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Franny` wants to fly from `DAL` but your schedule doesn't have any flights from `DAL`.

Comment: You are right, I use the incomplete file 'schedule.txt' and have this bug. Now, I change the file information and program works well. Thanks for help.